# custom tag takes null value from servlet and catch exception

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i wrote custom tag which makes it easy to localize strings;

in jsp it looks like this:

```
 <ct:word key="${message}"/>
```

message passed from servlet.
This tag takes needed string from the ResourceBundle.
Everything works but there is a problem. If i didn't pass message from servlet then my app throw Exception(ResourceBundle can not find the necessary string).
How to ensure that custom tag did not respond to null and skipped? like it does

```
<c:out />
```

code im my custom tag:

```
private String key;
private String value;

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public String getKey() {
    return this.key;
}

public int doStartTag() {
    try {
        this.checkLocale();//check locale and init resourceBundle
        value = resourceBundle.getString(key);
        pageContext.getOut().write(value);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    } catch (MyException e1) {
        logger.error(e1);
    }
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

I don't want to use

```
<c:if test="${not empty message}"/> or <c:when/>
```

it's clutters the code on jsp

**UPDATED**:
 i try

```
    } catch (MyException e1) {
        logger.error(e1);
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
```

but i have Exception:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
```

in my methods i catch

```
    catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        throw new MyException(Constants.ERROR_TRANSLATE_TAG,e);
    }
```

my app issues this exception ONLY if i I did not pass this message from servlet. I want to display page even if i dont have this message, without error pages.

Comment: Did you try catching `MissingResourceException`?

Comment: yes, to avoid pull all the exceptions, i throw MyException in try/catch block. Though I do not know how to handle this exception, i just write in log this error.

Comment: Well since you return `SKIP_BODY` and shouldn't get to the `pageContext.getOut().write(value);` line when a `MissinResourceException` is thrown everything should be fine. Or do you get an exception when the key should be set by the servlet? In that case, could you show us your tag description?

Comment: oh,this is a silly mistake, i need to catch MissingResourceException again for `resourceBundle.getString(key);` in doStartTag(). Thanks @Thomas for your help. This topic can be closed.

Comment: I'll add an answer for others who might find that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record:

`resourceBundle.getString(key);` will throw a `MissingResourceException` if the key cannot be found, thus catch that exception as well in the `doStartTag()` method.